# Get type of child class at runtime without RTTI in C++ from base pointer

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism, rtti

I have the problem that i need to check if a given type is the same as one specific one.

Simple example:

```
class Base {
   public:
    virtual void hi() = 0;
};

class A : public Base {
   public:
    void hi() { printf("Hi! I am A\n"); }
};

class B : public Base {
   public:
    void hi() { printf("Hi! I am B\n"); }
};

void isA(Base* something) {
    // 1
    if (something.is(A)) {
        A* aSomething = (A*)something;
        aSomething->hi();
    }

    // 2
    something->hi();
}
```

Output:

```
Hi! I am A
Hi! I am A
```

The problem is that i have no RTTI enabled (and can't enable it) so i do not have `dynamic_cast` or `typeid(...)`. But the program somehow still knows which type it is, as the part after `// 2` still works correctly including polymorphism.

In my exact scenareo, A is a template. So i only need to check if the given pointer to the base is of type A with the same template arguments.

Comment: _"i need to check if a given type is the same as one specific one"_ are you sure _you_ have to check what the type is?

Because you are using inheritance/dynamic polymorphism, thus you will already call the correct overload:
`A a{}; Base* b = &a; b.hi(); // will call A.hi();`
. RTTI seems doing the work twice, with twice the overhead. Please clarify the question. I mean _"But the program somehow still knows which type it is"_ that's the whole point of polymorphism!

Comment: Yes, this is right. The example might not be complete enough, but i didn't want to make it too long. For my case, i need to check if the type i am currently confronted with is the same as the one i got based on a pointer to the base class both have. Without RTTI, i can't check based on typeid, but as the polymorphism still works, there must be some kind of id still inside the instance of the class. Can i somehow read this out?

Comment: @T.M. Dynamic dispatch (a.k.a. virtual functions) does not depend on any type information.

Comment: I've removed the C++11 tag, since there's nothing relevant in the 2011 Standard. RTTI has been an integral part of C++ since 1998, and ISO has felt no need to introduce alternatives to RTTI in any standard since.

Comment: @molbdnilo: True, it's the other way around. `typeid` works at runtime for polymorphic types, and polymorphic types are defined as types that have virtual functions. The rationale is that it's trivial to add a hidden `__typeid` virtual function or similar mechanism.

Comment: If you tell us *WHY* you need the type info, we might know a way of doing that thing *without* knowing the type. Otherwise you can always add your own virtual typeid member function that returns "something" you can compare. Handmade RTTI :-)